# C++ Pointer in function Scope/Destruction

Tags: c++

Please forgive this question because it is likely along the lines of being elementary. Also, I have extensively googled this, but all I found were examples using implementations that quite obviously result in a memory leak.

Take note of the following pseudo code:

```
void myArbitraryFunc(){
...
// Create Pointer to parent class
MyParentClass* parent = (MyParentClass*)this.getParent();
parent->doSomething(someData);
...
}// Is parent destroyed here?
```

By destroyed I don't meam the parent class, I mean the pointer "parent", which I declared in the function body. It is destroyed when it falls out of scope, correct? If yes, why? And how would I create a duplicate of the class pointer without it being tied to the original parent?

Comment: The pointer `parent` is destroyed. For the same reason any local variable such as an `int` is destroyed. If you want it to persist, store it in a class member or return it.

Comment: @Neil Kirk thank you for clarifying that it is like an int. However, by returning the pointer, wouldn't I be passing access to the parent class? What if I just wanted to pass a doppleganger/unrelated duplicate?

Comment: Yes you would. Do you want to return a copy of the original object?

Comment: I feel as though these two questions go hand in hand. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer `parent` is destroyed.  What it points to, however, is *not* destroyed.

The pointer itself is just a variable on the stack, and goes away when the stack unwinds, when the current scope ends.  It is conceptually no different from this code:

```
void myArbitraryFunc() {
    ...
    int parent = 42;
    ....
} // parent goes away
```

The way to think about it is that a pointer is just a number, that number being the memory address of the object pointed to.

Now in your example, we presume that the MyParentClass object itself was created by something else, and is owned by something else, so `myArbitraryFunc` is not responsible for deleting it.

A pointer is really just a number, and "address" of the object.  Imagine memory as a giant set of boxes, with a number.  You ask the system to create an object, and it does so, and tells you that the object is in box 42.  Obviously writing copies of '42' isn't doing anything to the object itself.  It's just making lots of copies of the address.

Comment: As I posted above: "However, by returning the pointer, wouldn't I be passing access to the parent class? What if I just wanted to pass a doppleganger/unrelated duplicate?"

Comment: A pointer is just a number.  Think of it as a label.  `getParent` isn't returning an object.  It's returning a number that lets you find the object.

Comment: I understand that, but suppose I wanted to create a duplicate(unrelated pointer) that is full of what that object had at tbe time that the function was called without giving access to the first pointer class further down the application pipeline?

Comment: To create a copy of the object you can etiher use a assignment operator or copy constructor . If both are not implemented by the parent class , look at the declaration of the parent class to see if they provide a clone kind of interface . its advisable not to use the compiler defined assignment operator or copy constructor .